# Showing undefined value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this table where I fetch the data using firestore. There were some cases where this data is empty. I have this address where `city` is empty it would show `undefined`. How would I just display it as blank instead of the word "undefined"?

```
componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const users = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push({
            "User ID": doc.id,
            Address: data.address + ", " + data.city + ", " + data.provice,
                }),
          });
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: if `city`'s value is `null`, you can do this: `data.city ?? ''`. If `city`'s value is a String called 'undefined', then you can use an if statement. `String city = data.city; if (city == 'undefined') city = '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **+** you can do the following, It will simplify the code readability and cater to your use case.

```
 Address: `${data.address} , ${data.city || ""} , ${data.provice}`,
```

Answer (score 1):

use OR || operator if city is undefined

```
Address: data.address + ", " + data.city || "" + ", " + data.provice
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nullish coalescing operator.

`data.city ?? ""`